# Attributes are ignored in my app theme (style)

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-theme

I have base theme

```
<style name="BaseAppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
    ...
</style>
```

and `AppTheme` that inherits it

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="BaseAppTheme" >
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FFFF0000</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

and is used as the main theme of the app, i.e.

```
<application
...
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
... 
    >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
</application>
```

The problem is that attributes (eg `<item name="colorPrimary">#FFFF0000</item>` or `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/transparent</item>`, all of them) in `AppTheme` are ignored. However, if I add them to `BaseAppTheme` then they will work. Why are attributes ignored in `AppTheme` and how to fix it?

Comment: I tried the same and it is working fine! Try with some other color in statusBarColor! I tried with #C51D1D and works well!

Comment: @IR42 Maybe you use the BaseAppTheme somewhere, e.g. in <activity android:theme="@style/BaseAppTheme"

Comment: Try rebilding and clearing your cache, your problem might be from there!

Comment: Can you show the manifest file if your problem still persists? if not then you can mark my answer correct!

Comment: @AndriyD. nope, i have `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` in activity

Comment: @CodeDexter clean build and invalidate and restart didn't fix it

Comment: @IR42 do you have AppTheme only in values/styles.xml? Maybe do you have values-v21/styles.xml that contains AppTheme also or something like this?

Comment: You should try a fresh start with a new project! I think some where some part of your project is broken! If not then please share your manifest file!

Comment: @AndriyD. yes, i have `AppTheme` in `values\themes` and `values-v29\themes`, both ignored their attributes

Comment: @IR42 can you also provide values-v29\themes?

Comment: @IR42 do you change theme programmatically (setTheme(R.style. BaseAppTheme)) somewhere in the project?

Comment: @IR42 Does the issue occur only in one activity or do you use SingleActivity(and fragments)?

Comment: @AndriyD. i realized i added attrs to `value\themes` but tested on android 10 and didn't remove empty AppTheme in `values-v29\themes`.. feel stupid right now :) although this has happened before with `values-v29\themes` and android 10, thanks all for help

Comment: @IR42 great that you fix this. Can you please mark my answer as correct since I have pointed you where issue can be? thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have AppTheme only in values/styles.xml? Maybe do you have values-v21/styles.xml that contains AppTheme also so the problem is there or something like this?

Comment: Yup. That was it. This is madness. You'd naturally think the suffixed versions inherit and overwrite from the non-suffixed one.